# Unresponsive tab bar after returning to app from Link

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI project I have Links and Buttons that the user can tap and it takes them out of the app and into Safari. When I return to the app, the tab bar is unresponsive. It rarely works, you have to tap the tab multiple times for it to register.

I have no idea what is causing this issue. I will provide an example of the code with a Link that exhibits this behaviour and the message printed to the terminal.

Here is the code:

```
struct SettingsSheet: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("BG")
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        List {
                            Section(header: Text("Account Settings")) {
                                NavigationLink(
                                    destination: HelpView(),
                                    label: {
                                        Text("Help")
                                    })
                                NavigationLink(
                                    destination: RateAppView(),
                                    label: {
                                        Text("Rate This App")
                                    })
                                NavigationLink(
                                    destination: NotificationsView(),
                                    label: {
                                        Text("Notifications")
                                    })
                                NavigationLink(
                                    destination: LogOutView(),
                                    label: {
                                        Text("Log Out")
                                    })
                            }
                            
                            Section(header: Text("Information")) {
                                Link("Terms and Conditions", destination: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("TileText"))
                                Link("Privacy Policy", destination: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("TileText"))
                                NavigationLink(
                                    destination: DeleteAccountView(),
                                    label: {
                                        Text("Delete Account")
                                    })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Tab Bar:

```
struct MainPage: View {

    @StateObject var AppModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            TabView(selection: $AppModel.currentTab) {
                
                View1()
                    .tag(Tab.View1)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View2()
                    .tag(Tab.View2)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View3()
                    .tag(Tab.View3)
                    .setUpTab()
        
                View4()
                    .tag(Tab.View4)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View5()
                    .tag(Tab.View5)
                    .setUpTab()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                CustomTabBar(currentTab: $AppModel.currentTab, animation: animation)                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Tab
    var animation: Namespace.ID
    // Current Tab XValue...
    @State var currentXValue: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(Tab.allCases,id: \.rawValue){tab in
                TabButton(tab: tab)
                    .overlay {
                        Text(tab.rawValue)
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("TileText"))
                            .offset(y: currentTab == tab ? 15 : 100)
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top)
        // Preview wont show safeArea...
        .padding(.bottom,getSafeArea().bottom == 0 ? 15 : 10)
        .background{
            Color("TileColour")
                .shadow(color: Color("Black").opacity(0.08), radius: 5, x: 0, y: -5)
                .clipShape(BottomCurve(currentXValue: currentXValue))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
    // TabButton...
    @ViewBuilder
    func TabButton(tab: Tab)->some View{
        // Since we need XAxis Value for Curve...
        GeometryReader{proxy in
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                    currentTab = tab
                    // updating Value...
                    currentXValue = proxy.frame(in: .global).midX
                }
                
            } label: {
                // Moving Button up for current Tab...
                Image(tab.rawValue)
                // Since we need perfect value for Curve...
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(currentTab == tab ? .white : .gray.opacity(0.8))
                    .padding(currentTab == tab ? 15 : 0)
                    .background(
                        ZStack{
                            if currentTab == tab{
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(Color("LightBlue"))
                                    .shadow(color: Color("Black").opacity(0.1), radius: 8, x: 5, y: 5)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "TAB", in: animation)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .offset(y: currentTab == tab ? -50 : 0)
            }
            // Setting intial Curve Position...
            .onAppear {
                
                if tab == Tab.allCases.first && currentXValue == 0{
                    
                    currentXValue = proxy.frame(in: .global).midX
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
    }
}

// Making Case Iteratable...
// Tab Cases...
enum Tab: String,CaseIterable{
    
    // Raw Value must be image Name in asset..

    case View1 = "View1"
    case View2 = "View2"
    case View3 = "View3"
    case View4 = "View4"
    case View5 = "View5"

}

// Getting Safe Area...
extension View{
    func getSafeArea()->UIEdgeInsets{
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{
            return .zero
        }
        
        guard let safeArea = screen.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets else{
            return .zero
        }
        
        return safeArea
    }
}
```

Here is the message printed to the terminal when a tab icon is tapped but is not working:

> ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=58554, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}

UPDATE:
With further testing it seems the issue might be related to the sheet. In another part of the app I have a sheet that comes up halfway. If you use this sheet to tap a link when it is halfway up the screen, the UI bug does not happen however if you swipe up to extend the sheet to fill the screen, then tap the Link, the UI bug occurs.

Here is the code for the sheet functionality I am referring to:

```
.sheet(item: $selectedProduct) { item in
                            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                                ProductSheetView(product_id: item)
                                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                            } else {
                                // Fallback on earlier versions
                                ProductSheetView(product_id: item)
                            }
                        }
```

UPDATE:
I just used some a .onChange method to set showing the sheet to false after going into the background but this DID NOT FIX the unresponsive tab bar issue. Here is the code I added:

```
Button(action:{
                            self.showSettingsSheet.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("BlackWhite"))
                        })
                        .padding(.trailing)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showSettingsSheet) {
                            NavigationView {
                                SettingsSheet()
                            }
                        }

                        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { scenePhase in
                                    if scenePhase == .background {
                                        showSettingsSheet = false
                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: `...when a tab icon is tapped but is not working:`, what `tab` icons are you talking about? I don't see any in your code. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with at least the code that does not work.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I will update the question to include all the code for the tab bar